# Android ListView DPAD navigation: Why do I have to the click up button twice to scroll up?

Tags: android, listview

I am navigating a simple listView with a remote control, using DPAD_UP to go up & DPAD_DOWN to go down the list. I am not doing anything special beyond the vanilla stuff you see going on below. Each time I click the down button it scrolls to the next row down just fine. However, when going the reverse direction (i.e. clicking the up button) I have to click it twice to scroll up a row except for a select few # of rows which consistently work.

Each time I click the up button the OnItemSelectedListener is fired. For example, I am at position 10, I hit the up button, onItemSelected(pos=10) is fired. I hit the up button again, now the listview scrolls up and onItemSelected(pos=9) is fired. I repeat, no change in listView & onItemSelected(pos=9), etc.

Using Jelly Bean, API Level 17, this is not touchscreen.

Fragment Code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.ListView;
...
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
  ListView mListView = null;
  ChListAdapter mChListAdapter = null;
  ...
  @Override onCreateView(...) {
    mListView = (ListView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.chListView);
    mChListAdapter = new ChListAdapter()
    mListView.setAdapter(mChListAdapter);
    mListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        android.util.Log.e(TAG,"POS: " + position);
      }
    ...
  }
  ...
  @Override onResume(...) {
    mListView.requestFocus();
  }
  ...
  public void setSelectedCh(int chId) { // request from Activity
    mListView.setSelection(<private method to get pos from chId>);
  }
  ...
  class ChListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Stuff> {
    public ChListAdapter() {
      super(getActivity(), R.layout.row_ch, R.id.row_ch_name,<list in here>);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

      TextView txt1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_ch_name);
      txt1.setText(...);
      
      TextView txt2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_ch_number);
      txt2.setText(...);
      
      ImageView imgView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_ch_image);
      imgView.setImageDrawable(logoBitmapDrawable);
      
      return row;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

FRAGMENT XML:

```
<LinearLayout...
  <LinearLayout...
    ...
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:layout_weight="100"
      android:baselineAligned="false"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingBottom="3dp"
          android:paddingLeft="10dp"
          android:paddingTop="3dp"
          android:text="@string/asdf" />
        <ListView
          android:id="@+id/chListView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
          android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    ...
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

LISTVIEW ROW XML (/layout/row_ch.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_ch_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/aaa" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_ch_number"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="bbb" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_ch_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:text="ccc"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ps - I forgot to mention I've tried every permutation I can think of for setItemsCanFocus(), setFocusable(), and setDescendantFocusability() on the listView, linearLayouts & Image/TextViews in each row